# Not getting the Name of Enum type with Automapper

Tags: c#, enums, mapping, automapper

Want to get the name of the enum. I get 0 and 1 only.How to get convert this of mapping with Automapper. Anyone suggest solution for this. My code is as below :-

```
public class Work
{
     public ScheduleType Schedule { get; set; }
}

public enum ScheduleType
{
    Standard,
    Matrix
}

public static class EnumMapValue 
{
    public static ScheduleType MapScheduleType(string value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case "S":                    
                return ScheduleType.Standard; 
            case "M":
                return ScheduleType.Matrix;
            default:
                return ScheduleType.Standard;;
        }
    }
}

public class WorkProfile : Profile
{
   public WorkProfile()
   {
      IMappingExpression<DataRow, WorkOrder> mappingExpression;
      mappingExpression = CreateMap<DataRow, WorkOrder>();

      mappingExpression.ForMember(d => d.ScheduleType, o => o.MapFrom(s =>            
                  EnumMapValue.ScheduleType(s["SCHEDULE_TYPE"].ToString())));
   }
}
```

Comment: can you show example data and complete all object(for exmaple:WorkOrder,DataRow)?this point you want is similar this is site https://sudonull.com/post/818-Get-the-enum-data-in-the-Automapper-projection

Comment: Yes, [By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum). If you want to show the enum value as string instead of integer, possibly that you need to convert the `Schedule` property as string type (or create another property to hold the string value) and cast the enum to string.